# How format specifiers works with scanf in loop in C?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

This code works correctly :

```
int main()
{
    int i,n=2;
    char str[50];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts("Enter a name");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }

return 0;
}
```

---

And reads two input, writes them.

Questions :

1. What is `%[^\n]%*c`? especially `%*c`? How it works?
2. When i change that line to `scanf("%[^\n]", str)` it does not take second input.why?

Comment: It "works correctly" until you enter a string that has more than 49 characters before the first newline.

Comment: It's all explained in the manual.

Comment: `%[^\n]` consumes anything except a newline.  `%*c` consumes the newline.  If you omit the `%*c`, then the newline is never consumed and subsequent calls to scanf return without consuming anything.  In each case, `scanf` returns 0.  You should *always* check the value returned by scanf.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", str)` works perfectly well (except that it is bad practice and liable to undefined behavior).  It just doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", str)` does not works with two input. it only read one input. But in code i want read two input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `scanf`, `%*c` means that take one character of input, but don't actually store it in anything. So try to visualize this. In the first run of the loop, when you enter, say, `behzad namdaryan`, `stdin` will look something like this:

```
behzad namdaryan\n
```

Now, `%[^\n]` takes input as a string until it reaches `\n`. It will *NOT* count `\n` in the input, it'll leave it there. So if this were `scanf("%[^\n]", str);` in the loop instead, after the first run, `stdin` would look like this:

```
\n
```

As you can see, `\n` is still there. Now every time it does `scanf` again, it'll immediately find `\n` and leave it there and won't actually prompt you for input (because `stdin` is not empty). `%*c` takes care of this. Every time after you take the string as input, that `%*c` removes and disposes of the last `\n` in the stream so the stream becomes empty and you can take input again.

Comment: Very useful Explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In a `scanf` format string, `%[^\n]` says to match all characters other than a new-line character. `%*c` says to match a character but not assign it to an input.

Since `%[^\n]` will match all characters until it finds a new-line character, the `%*c` will consume that new-line character without storing it. The characters matched by `%[^\n]` will be stored in `str`.