# Problem with the %[^,] thing while using scanf for stdin

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char word[20];
    char cat[20];
    printf("Enter the thing:");
    scanf("%[^,]",word);
    scanf("%[^,]",cat);
    printf("%s",word);
    printf("%s",cat);
    return 0;
}
```

So here's my code, it prints out the value for word, but not the value for cat?

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't call this a duplicate, but there's this related question where the issue revolves around this specific thing about `%[^`: [How format specifiers works with scanf in loop in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67268601)

Answer (score 3):

After the first scan, `,` is left in the input stream. You need to add `,` to the matching pattern: `[^,],`.

Always check if `scanf` succeeds (in these cases, returns `1`) and always limit the input to the number of characters you have space for in the buffer `-1`, so `%19[^,],` in both cases here. If the second scan does not need a `,` skip adding that to the pattern matching.

Combining both scans:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char word[20];
    char cat[20];
    printf("Enter the thing:");

    // in this version, "cat" doesn't need to be followed by a comma
    if(scanf("%19[^,],%19[^,]", word, cat) == 2) {
        printf(">%s<\n", word);
        printf(">%s<\n", cat);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, the comma could be added to the beginning of the format for the next `scanf` (`",%19[^,]"`), or the distinction is lost if the multiple `scanf` calls are coalesced into one.

Comment: Alternatively, the comma could be added to the beginning of the format for the *next* `scanf`, or the distinction is lost if the multiple `scanf` calls are coalesced into one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point! I'll copy that into the answer _as-is_. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way `%[^` works is that it keeps scanning characters until it finds one of the characters in its list (in your case that's only `,`, But it doesn't actually eat up that character and stays at that point. So visualizing the issue, say you enter `Foo, bar,` as input when prompted, `scanf("%[^,]",word);` will scan `Foo` and the file position will be moved to the start of `, bar`. Upon calling `scanf("%[^,]",cat);`, the `,` will immediately be seen and nothing will be scanned.

To fix this, you need to change the format string to eat up the `,` afterwards:

```
scanf("%[^,],",word); // Notice the ',' after ']'
scanf(" %[^,],",cat); /* A leading ' ' will leave out any whitespace between `,` and
                         the next string */
```

Example of running the fixed program:

```
Enter the thing:Foo, bar,
Foobar
```

Comment: And there's a space at the start of the `cat` string because scan sets (`%[…]`) do not skip leading white space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I chose not to add that because I didn't know if OP wanted that behavior (same reason why I've kept the second comma unlike Ted, even though it looks rather odd) and it wasn't exactly related to the specific issue. But I'll just edit to fix my answer.